# Как в список добавить словарь?

Tags: python

При добавлении в список `test` словаря при помощи

```
test.append('{"name": "' + name+ '", "number":"' + number + '}')
```

получается так, что добавляется строка, а не словарь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вы добавляете строку, а не словарь.

```
test.append({'name': name, 'number': number})
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сначала создать словарь, а затем добавить его в список с помощью `.append()`.

```
a = []
b = { 'c': 1, 'd': 2 }
a.append(b)
```

Таким образом в один список можно добавить несколько словарей.